# Running `npm ci` returns `pkg-dir not accessible from find-cache-dir`

Tags: npm, node-modules, package-lock.json

I'm trying to run this command:

`npm ci`

And it returns this error:

`npm ERR! pkg-dir not accessible from find-cache-dir`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

So it turned out that my `package-lock.json` file was out of sync with `package.json`. I ran `npm i`, which regenerated an in-sync version of `package-lock.json`, which I eventually used in other environments to successfully run `npm ci` command.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but this solution isn't working for me.

Comment: @IanGilham Did anything work for you? Issues like these are annoying, and it'd be good to know what worked for you for future reference.

Comment: I got it working after downgrading npm to version **6.4.1**, which is the same version used by our automated build system.It turns out that there is absolutely no guarantee that `package-lock.json` files are compatible with minor releases of npm itself, so they need constant regeneration. I'm not sure if the two observations are related, however.

Answer (score 3):

Just running `npm i` again didn't fix the issue for me. Deleting my existing `package-lock.json` and my `node_modules` folder, then running `npm i` generated an updated `package-lock.json` file. Afterwards, `npm ci` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with compatibility between versions of Node and NPM, in my case upgrading NPM to 8.5.5 and Node to 18.12.1 worked